# Exit Code 11 installing Persistent (Yesod)

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod, persistent

I'm trying to install Yesod on my Mac (running Mavericks), but installation fails because of an error installing Persistent. Specifically, `cabal install persistent` yields:

```
Failed to install persistent-1.3.0.2
Updating documentation index /Users/Max/Library/Haskell/doc/index.html
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
persistent-1.3.0.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 11
```

[(The full output is available as a gist)](https://gist.github.com/MaxGabriel/8500348)

I don't think this is an issue with conflicts, because I ran `rm -rf ~/.ghc ~/.cabal` before trying this (though I think 3 globally installed packages might not have been erased—unsure).

I'm using the latest Haskell Platform with the `ghc-clang-wrapper` script.

Cabal versions:

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library
```

GHC version:

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://old.hackage.haskell.org/trac/hackage/ticket/777

Comment: How did you install your yesod ?

Comment: You should update your cabal, and remember to use install `yesod-platform` (if you weren't already doing that)

Comment: The error is a type mismatch. I looked at it briefly yesterday, but got nowhere. It looks like one of the libraries that persistent depends on changed its API.

Comment: @Ralph could this possibly be Aeson? I heard it started breaking some things with ~0.7 or smth

Comment: The error I got had something to do with `Data.Scientific.Scientific`. I was also installing the MongoDB persistence library. I played with it for a few minutes, but gave up. I'm looking at Snap (http://snapframework.com/) now.

Comment: @Chrules I tried `yesod-platform`—same issue. @sibi I've tried `cabal install yesod` and `cabal install yesod-platform`, clearing out installed packages between tries.

Comment: Hmm it also failed when I tried to build it by cloning [the repo](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent). I'll try with a newer version of Cabal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling Haskell platform allowed me to install Persistent, but the real issue was that I needed to install `gcc48`. Installing this cleared everything up. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21285413/1176156