# Cabal 1.18 gives Bus Error 10 on nearly everything on OS X

Tags: haskell, cabal

I upgraded Cabal from the 1.16 version that came with Haskell Platform to 1.18, but nearly every command immediately dies with `Bus error: 10`:

```
$ cabal install aeson
Bus error: 10

$ cabal sandbox init
Bus error: 10

$ cabal list
Bus error: 10
```

(`cabal help` still works, though)

OS version: OS X Mavericks 10.9.1

Cabal versions:

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.18.0.2
using version 1.18.1.2 of the Cabal library
```

GHC version:

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3
```

Comment: If it were me I'd just build a fresh copy of it. Probably something strange happened during this build and a fresh try will straighten things out.

Comment: I tried a straight reinstall (`cabal install cabal-install`, starting from the 1.16 version) but had the same issue. Maybe if I uninstall/reinstall Haskell Platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had similar problem with cabal. Installing real gcc seems to help (at least on OS X 10.8.5 Mountain Lion with Xcode 5.0.2):

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install gcc48
# go for lunch ... or maybe movie
```

Then edit `/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.6.3-i386/usr/lib/ghc-7.6.3/settings` (as root) and put

```
("C compiler command", "/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8"),
```

instead of `/usr/bin/gcc`

Then

```
rm -rf ~/.ghc ~/.cabal ~/Library/Haskell
```

As usual be careful with `rm -rf` but it seems necessary as cached version of Cabal-the-library lead to bus error even with `gcc-4.8` (which suggests the problem may be with the Cabal library rather than cabal-install itself).

NB the fresh install of Haskell Platform alone did not work for me, either with or without various clang wrappers.

Comment: Hm, I'm still having problems with installing various packages, so I'm going to give this a shot. Thanks @mbenke

Comment: Thank you so much; once I installed gcc48 everything came together!